# Sorting sentences into paragraphs

Tags: python, sorting, nlp

I want to arrange a set of sentences into paragraphs automatically, at the moment Im reading from a file the sentences and measuring the string distance between them. I was thinking that the next logical step would be to find something else with which to classify the sentences, and then use this two attributes to divide to plot the sentences in a graph and then apply a KMeans algorithm to them that would help me devise which sentences are similar to each other and therefor which ones are going into the same paragraphs. This has proven to be harder than I thought, I would therefore appreciate any input in either, the second attribute I can use to measure the tweets, a different approach or a tool that does this for me. Below is the code I'm currently using

```
import re
import math
from collections import Counter
import itertools


#first understadn this code so that we can manipulate it.
WORD = re.compile(r'\w+')

def get_cosine(vec1, vec2):
    intersection =  set(vec1.keys()) & set(vec2.keys())
    numerator = sum([vec1[x] * vec2[x] for x in intersection])

    sum1 = sum([vec1[x]**2 for x in vec1.keys()])
    sum2 = sum([vec2[x]**2 for x in vec2.keys()])
    denominator = math.sqrt(sum1) * math.sqrt(sum2)

    if not denominator:
        return 0.0
    else:
        return float(numerator) / denominator

def text_to_vector(text):
    words = WORD.findall(text)
    return Counter(words)

#count the number of tweets set it to a variable and then set it as the length of this or  what ever
#This is where the text comes from
with open("positive copy.txt", "r") as pt:
    lines = pt.readlines()
    # Count how many lines we have
    count = len(lines)
    # Create a count * count size matrix
    Matrix = [[1 for x in range(count)] for y in range(count)] 
    # Loop through lines assigning x as the number of line we're on and lineA as it's text
    for x, lineA in enumerate(lines):
        vectorA = text_to_vector(lineA)
        for y, lineB in enumerate(itertools.islice(lines, count - x)):
            vectorB = text_to_vector(lineB)
            cosine = get_cosine(vectorA, vectorB)
            print lineA, lineB, "\n Cosine:", cosine, "\n"
            Matrix[y][x]=get_cosine(vectorA, vectorB)
            Matrix[x][y]=get_cosine(vectorA, vectorB)
    print Matrix
```

and here is the sample data I'm using to run my tests

```
Hello my name is Jeff
Hello everyone I’m named Jeff
this has absolutely nothing to do
everyone Im a doctor
hello I don’t even know whats happening
whats  happening is that you not know
```

This are my results as of now:

```
[[0.9999999999999998, 0.33806170189140655, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.16903085094570328], [0.33806170189140655, 0.9999999999999999, 0.0, 0.1889822365046136, 0.13363062095621217, 1], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0000000000000002, 0.0, 1, 1], [0.0, 0.1889822365046136, 0.0, 1, 1, 1], [0.0, 0.13363062095621217, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0.16903085094570328, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

While these are the results expected for the code above, I want to be able to output a set of values that I can plot into a graph. Or a way to derive into which paragraph I should assign each paragraph, this is more of a knowledge question than a code one, although any helpful code is more than welcomed

Comment: Great so far. Now add your expected results and actual results to your post to make it clear what the problem is.

Comment: Not to discourage you in this direction, but I don't think sentences within paragraphs have significantly more *similarity* than sentences from different-but-adjacent paragraphs, at least for notions of similarity I can think of.  

Maybe you would have more luck with a [CRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_random_field) to tag sentences as openers, continuers, and closers?

Comment: While this is true, the only purpose of dividing them into paragraphs is to then apply a summarisation algorithm with .nltk this algorithm works way better when the text is arranged into paragraphs, thus my insistence on doing so, just a stepping stone to improve the performance of another algorithm.